# Double Integral with Variable Limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integration $\int_{0}^{\infty} \phi(x,V_1) dx \int_{x}^{\infty} \phi(x',V_2) dx'$. Where $\phi(x,V) = \frac{1}{V} e^{-\frac{x}{V}}$.

I am getting confused on how to handle the variable lower limit in the second integral. Any reference to relevant material where I can learn more about this form of integral would be very helpful.

I ultimately have to prove that $p(V_1, V_2) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \phi(x,V_1) dx \int_{x}^{\infty} \phi(x',V_2) dx' \approx \frac{V_1}{V_1 + V_2}$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you asking about $\frac{1}{V_1\,V_2}\int_0^{\infty}\int_x^{\infty}\,e^{-y/V_2}\,e^{-x/V_1}\,dy\,dx$ ?

Comment: @popi Thanks. That suggestion solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop here, as @popi mentioned in the comments, $p(V_1, V_2) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{V_1}e^{\frac{x}{V_1}}dx\int_x^{\infty}\frac{1}{V_2}e^{\frac{x'}{V_2}}dx' \text{ can be simplified to } \frac{1}{V_1V_2}\int_0^{\infty}\int_x^{\infty}e^{\frac{x'}{V_2}}e^{\frac{x}{V_1}} dx'dx$, where we integrate with respect to $dx'$ first before integrating w.r.t to x. Note that when integrating with respect to $dx'$ we will inherit an $x$ from the limits which will be then integrated over when integrating with respect to $dx$.